# UWP Media.Capture as a source for WebRTC

Tags: uwp, webrtc, ms-media-foundation, system.windows.media

I would like to capture a media using this [Windows.Media.Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) as a Stream for WebRTC. The reason for that is, that I would like to use the [`AddVideoEffectAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture#Windows_Media_Capture_MediaCapture_AddVideoEffectAsync_Windows_Media_Effects_IVideoEffectDefinition_Windows_Media_Capture_MediaStreamType_) method to apply my custom Effect. Is that possible? And if not, what are the option of transformation of media, that is streamed by WebRTC?

Answer (score 0):

How you do this depends on the WebRTC stack you're using but in general, the `GetPreviewFrameAsync` method on the MediaCapture class will give you the bitmap which can be used to get the raw frame data you'd need to encode the video frame for WebRTC.